# How to Send Drawable as a parameter to a function

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am trying to set Imageview using a function

that if we send Image drawable to a function that function set that drawable to the respective Imageview.

This is function code in which it gets "id" and after that respective id function will call

```
public void showpeg(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        showSeagreen(R.drawable.seagreen);
        break;
    }

}
```

This is my ShowSeagreen() function

```
public void showSeagreen(Drawable draw) {
    if (iRow == 1) {
        if (iPlace == 1) {
            seagreen = 1;
            one_first.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draw);
            iPlace++;
        } else if (iPlace == 2) {
            seagreen = 2;
            one_two.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draw);
            iPlace++;
        }
 }
```

I know i am doing it wrong but i can't find a way to do this Please any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: it does not compile as `showSeagreen` receives `Drawable` and you´re sending an `int`

Comment: @eduyayo Right I got it, but how can i send a drawable to showSeagreen

Comment: Indeed you messed up `Drawable` object (which is a ready-to-use drawable) and a drawable id, which simply represents it, but is not exploitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

`showSeagreen(R.drawable.seagreen);`

use:

```
showSeagreen(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seagreen));
```

Comment: You are Amazing, its too simple (Y) 
Working fine

Comment: NP glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

Any Resources is a int.
Do like this to "showSeagreen":

```
public void showSeagreen(int draw) {
    if (iRow == 1) {
        if (iPlace == 1) {
            seagreen = 1;
            one_first.setBackgroundResource(draw);
            iPlace++;
        } else if (iPlace == 2) {
            seagreen = 2;
            one_two.setBackgroundResource(draw);
            iPlace++;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Using your Ans and the Ans I selected I got my problem solved.
Amazing And Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If what i understand from your question is true then i think your aim is to add drawable image as a parameter if thats what you want
then you should add the

```
  @DrawableRes int draw
```

like

```
public void showSeagreen(@DrawableRes int draw) {

}
```

as your parameter then you can add drawable files in here